# Calculate principal stresses

Tags: matlab

Code result fails to appear here in the table produced by it.

In essence only the fifth row fills up for some reason. Aim of this code is to calculate principal stresses with MATLAB. No clue what specifically went wrong.

```
syms
sigma_max sigma_min tau_max alpha primary_direction_x_x_value primary_direction_x_y_value primary_direction_y_x_value primary_direction_y_y_value
    
sigma_max=0.5*((sigma_xx)+(sigma_yy))+sqrt(0.25*(((sigma_xx)-(sigma_yy))^2)+(sigma_xy)^2); %physics
sigma_min=0.5*((sigma_xx)+(sigma_yy))-sqrt(0.25*(((sigma_xx)-(sigma_yy))^2)+(sigma_xy)^2);
tau_max=0.5*((sigma_max)-(sigma_min)); 
%physics
alpha=(180/pi)*0.5*(atan((2*sigma_xy)/(sigma_xx-sigma_yy)));
primary_direction_x_x_value=cosd(alpha);
primary_direction_x_y_value=sind(alpha);
%
primary_direction_y_x_value=-sind(alpha);
primary_direction_y_y_value=cosd(alpha);
%physics
xx=[60 200 900 400 0];
yy=[0 -200 100 800 240];
xy=[40 -200 200 600 120];
    
for n = 1:length(xx)
    sigma_xx=xx(n);
    sigma_yy=yy(n);
    sigma_xy=xy(n);
    A=zeros(1,5);   
    A(n)=sigma_max; 
    B=zeros(1,5);   
    B(n)=sigma_min; 
    H=zeros(1,5);  
    H(n)=tau_max;
    C=zeros(1,5);   
    C(n)=alpha; 
    D=zeros(1,5);   
    D(n)=primary_direction_x_x_value;
    E=zeros(1,5);   
    E(n)=primary_direction_x_y_value;
    F=zeros(1,5);   
    F(n)=primary_direction_y_x_value;
    G=zeros(1,5);   
    G(n)=primary_direction_y_y_value;
end
    
varNames = {'σ max [Mpa]';'σ min [Mpa]';'tau max [Mpa]';'alpha [°]';'primary direction x x value';'primary direction x y value';'primary direction y x value';'primary direction y y value'};
T=table(A',B',H',C',D',E',F',G','VariableNames',varNames)
```

Comment: If you fixed your code based on input from my answer, please accept the answer. Also typically in this situation, you don't [edit] the post to add a solution, but add your own answer to your question detailing how/why the problem is solved.  Someone else looks at this now and they don't know what the original post looked like. I rolled back your changes for this reason. **Please add the solution as an answer**.

Comment: No problem, I'm on it...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the initialization statements like `A=zeros(1,5);`  be outside of the loop?

Right now for each `n` the vectors `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` and `G` are cleared overwriting them with all zeros.

Comment: It helped. I made several more changes but could not have moved further without your hint for sure. I'll add the entire code a bit later as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
syms n
format bank
 A=zeros(1,5); 
 B=zeros(1,5);  
 H=zeros(1,5);  
 C=zeros(1,5);   
 D=zeros(1,5);   
 E=zeros(1,5);   
 F=zeros(1,5);   
 G=zeros(1,5);
 I=zeros(1,5);
 J=zeros(1,5);
 K=zeros(1,5);
  


Input=[60 200 900 400 0
0 -200 100 800 240
40 -200 200 600 120]';
    
for n = 1:5
 
    sigma_xx=Input(n,1); 
    sigma_yy=Input(n,2);
    sigma_xy=Input(n,3);
sigma_max=0.5*((sigma_xx)+(sigma_yy))+sqrt(0.25*(((sigma_xx)-(sigma_yy))^2)+(sigma_xy)^2);%physics
sigma_min=0.5*((sigma_xx)+(sigma_yy))-sqrt(0.25*(((sigma_xx)-(sigma_yy))^2)+(sigma_xy)^2);%physics
tau_max=0.5*((sigma_max)-(sigma_min)); %physics
alpha=(180/pi)*0.5*(atan((2*sigma_xy)/(sigma_xx-sigma_yy)));%physics
primary_direction_x_x_value=cosd(alpha);%physics
primary_direction_x_y_value=sind(alpha);%physics
primary_direction_y_x_value=-sind(alpha);%physics
primary_direction_y_y_value=cosd(alpha);%physics

 sigma_xxRe= 0.5*((sigma_xx)+(sigma_yy))+0.5*(((sigma_xx)-(sigma_yy))*cosd(2*alpha))+(sigma_xy)*sind(2*alpha);%physics - Rotation of stress component. 
 sigma_yyRe= 0.5*((sigma_xx)+(sigma_yy))-0.5*(((sigma_xx)-(sigma_yy))*cosd(2*alpha))-(sigma_xy)*sind(2*alpha);%physics
 sigma_xyRe=0.5*((-(sigma_xx)+(sigma_yy))*sind(2*alpha))+(sigma_xy)*cosd(2*alpha);%physics
 
    A(n)=sigma_max; 
    B(n)=sigma_min; 
    H(n)=tau_max;
    C(n)=alpha;
    D(n)=primary_direction_x_x_value;
    E(n)=primary_direction_x_y_value;
    F(n)=primary_direction_y_x_value;
    G(n)=primary_direction_y_y_value;
    I(n)=sigma_xxRe;
    J(n)=sigma_yyRe;
    K(n)=sigma_xyRe;
end

varNames = {'σ max [Mpa]';'σ min [Mpa]';'tau max [Mpa]';'alpha [°]';'primary direction x x value';'primary direction x y value';'primary direction y x value';'primary direction y y value';'σ xx revolved';'σ yy revolved';'σ xy revolved'};
T=table(A',B',H',C',D',E',F',G',I',J',K','VariableNames',varNames)
```

This code solves the problem since
1.A=zeros(1,5) no longer annihlates all that was put into it when it was in the loop, but rather it SAVES it in proper cells.
2.The input was changed to one single matrix since for some reason it is much easier for the loop to deal with a whole coherent matrix rather than several vectors, each of which contains some part of input data necessary for calculation.
3. May this be useful to whomever might need to calculate principal stresses...
[Example of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxWqx.png)